# Separation of concerns

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a question about separation of concerns in Laravel 4.

Let's took an example to illustrate my question.

My process is : Record an invoice

So, I would have 2 controllers : Invoice and Customer

In order to separate the logic, is it right to do a Service class that includes both Invoice and Customer controller and have a method recordInvoice() in this service that can call methods from invoice and customer?

How to have a class upper the Controller? (Model->Controller->Service)
Do you know how to do that in Laravel 4?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is, how to separate the business logic away from controllers. In your example you have two controllers that need to execute the same business logic of recording an invoice.

There are several ways to do it. You can use the Eloquent ORM and add a method to a model class of invoice. In which case both controllers can access it. Or you can create a library and add a class that just manages your invoices.

Here's a good tutorial on creating a library: http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading

If you want to learn more about models you should read the laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

If I'm off base let me know. I would ask in comments but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must consider "dependency injection" at this point. `Invoice` object has a dependency on `Customer`. So you can create `Invoice` class that accepts a `Customer` object in its constructor. Invoice object can have a function `create()`which can manipulate `Customer` to get information about `Customer` while creating `Invoice`